# MTKView - Resizing Texture To Fill View

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metal, metalkit

I am very new to Metal, but diligently working to follow Apple's [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) sample project.  The project demonstrates using a MTKView as a preview for an AVCaptureSession.

I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to have my MTKView render "full screen" (specifically on iPhone X, XS, and 3rd generation iPad Pro).  While my constraints are set properly in the Storyboard, my camera preview is scaled to a different aspect ratio, and not full screen.

As a test, I set;

`self.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)`

in my MTKView's init, confirming that the MTKView is the proper size (I can see the red background in the problematic areas, but my camera preview does not stretch to fill the screen).

I am of the belief that my issue exists in this calculation;

```
// Calculate scale.
if textureWidth > 0 && textureHeight > 0 {
  switch textureRotation {
    case .rotate0Degrees, .rotate180Degrees:
      scaleX = Float(internalBounds.width / CGFloat(textureWidth))
      scaleY = Float(internalBounds.height / CGFloat(textureHeight))

    case .rotate90Degrees, .rotate270Degrees:
      scaleX = Float(internalBounds.width / CGFloat(textureHeight))
      scaleY = Float(internalBounds.height / CGFloat(textureWidth))
   }
}

// Resize aspect ratio.
resizeAspect = min(scaleX, scaleY)
if scaleX < scaleY {
  scaleY = scaleX / scaleY
  scaleX = 1.0
} else {
  scaleX = scaleY / scaleX
  scaleY = 1.0
}
```

In my test environment, my texture size is 2400x1800 and my internal bounds are 834x1194.  While I recognize the difference in aspect ratio, I am trying to figure out the correct math to have the texture fill the entire display (even if that means it is scaled slightly less and I lose some of the texture on the sides).

Could anyone advise?  Thanks!

Comment: There will be a "viewport" somewhere that needs to be updated with the new size of the view.  This viewport will be set on the [`MTLRenderCommandEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder?language=objc) during rendering.  This is what affects the size of the rendered output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @trojanfoe.  I checked my MTLView file, and the provided documentation, but nothing in the file seems to reference a viewport.  Specifically, [this](https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/blob/master/AVCamPhotoFilter/AVCamPhotoFilter/PreviewMetalView.swift) file is the one I am working on, and the `draw()` function, I believe, is where the "viewport" would be set, though the working sample from Apple has no such reference.

Comment: It's in the `MTKView` delegate `MTKView:drawableSizeWillChange:` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @trojanfoe.  Regretfully, I don't think I have a `MTKViewDelegate` in this project.  I searched the entire sample and don't have a `drawableSizeWillChange` method anywhere.

Comment: OK I actually downloaded and looked at the sample and it seems to be deriving size from the `internalPixelBuffer` which is sized on `self.bounds` and so it should "just work" regardless of the size of the view (as you would expect).  You should probably suspect your constraint configuration.  Sorry for wasting your time with assumptions over the implementation,

Comment: No problem, @trojanfoe.  Thank you for looking into it!  What's curious is that if I set a background color on my `MTKView`, the "empty" areas show the background color properly.  It leads me to believe my constraints are correct, but the scaling of the camera preview is not taking into account the updated screen sizes on newer devices.  I actually found another Apple sample project that has a similar Metal preview, but does function as I expect, and am working to comb through the code to find the difference.  I will update the question if I can figure it out!

Comment: Any update? encountering the same issue @ZbadhabitZ

Answer (score 6):

```
// Resize aspect ratio.
resizeAspect = min(scaleX, scaleY)

if scaleX < scaleY {
  scaleY = scaleX / scaleY
  scaleX = 1.0
} else {
  scaleX = scaleY / scaleX
  scaleY = 1.0
}
```

Replace with

```
// Resize aspect ratio.
// For AspectFill Screen scaleX > scaleY
// For AspectFit Screen scaleX < scaleY
    
resizeAspect = min(scaleX, scaleY)
if scaleX > scaleY {
   scaleY = scaleX / scaleY
   scaleX = 1.0
} else {
   scaleX = scaleY / scaleX
  scaleY = 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Open PreviewMetalView.swift

Replace following lines:
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(previewPixelBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(previewPixelBuffer)

with following lines: 
let previewViewWidth = Int(self.frame.size.width)
let previewViewheight = Int(self.frame.size.height)
let isPortrait = previewViewheight > previewViewWidth
let width = isPortrait ? previewViewheight : previewViewWidth
let height = isPortrait ? previewViewWidth : previewViewheight
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it may your answer solves the problem but it also expected to explain your solution in at least a few sentences. it helps your answer be more readable. please try to add it by editing your answer.

Comment: Captured Image won't be the same as PreviewView. Don't you think that's important to mention here?