# How to resize camera capture processed by Metal shaders to full-screen?

Tags: swift, metalkit

I want to create a full-screen camera app, which uses metal shaders. When I used to use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in my root View, with settings `[videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill][1]` it was really full screen, but when I switched my app to Metal, I can't resize it more than 1170 x 1560 for iPhone 13 pro. The only settings that I found according to this manual https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream
is:

```
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(previewPixelBuffer)

let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(previewPixelBuffer)
```

I am absolutely new to Metal, so maybe I can't ask the correct answer, but how can I resize Metal texture to full-screen size?
//        width = 1170
//        height = 1560

```
private func render() {
    guard let pixelBuffer = self.pixelBuffer else { return }
    var width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    var height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    
            
    var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
    print(width)
    print(height)
    CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache!, pixelBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height , 0, &cvTextureOut)
    
    guard let cvTexture = cvTextureOut, let inputTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture) else {
        fatalError("Failed to create metal textures")
    }
    
    guard let drawable: CAMetalDrawable = self.currentDrawable else { fatalError("Failed to create drawable") }
    
    if let commandQueue = commandQueue, let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(), let computeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() {
        computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture, index: 0)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, index: 1)
        computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(inputTexture.threadGroups(), threadsPerThreadgroup: inputTexture.threadGroupCount())
        computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817589/mtkview-resizing-texture-to-fill-view